# Raising a matrix to a power using Math.pow()?

Tags: java, math, matrix

How can I raise a matrix to a certain power using the command `Math.pow()`? I've already coded a method to do it manually but I want another just for testing, using `Math.pow()`.

Comment: the multiplication of two matrices is different than the multiplication of two numerical digits. Please do a research first of how to multiply a matrix M1 with matrix M2.

Comment: For testing, use a matrix library which implements it.

Comment: @KarelG I've already coded a method to multiply to matrix manually, I was only asking if there was a short answer to my problem. I'll do what Andy Turner sugested. Thank you.

Comment: You can use it for testing diagonal matrices only (which is certainly not enough for testing your routine "for real").

Comment: I think it could be possible for some cells to be computed with the pow but the pain of obtaining the equations and added overhead is not worth the time... anyway you can use power by squaring method for your matrix powering instead ... that will change from `O(n)` matrix multiplications to `O(log2(n))` ...

Answer (score 4):

The short answer - you can't. [`Math#pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-) takes two `double`s. If you want a logical power operation on your own datatype, you'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: @KarelG, yes, it could, but why would it be? It is an answer to the question

Comment: I think when you derive the equation `A^n` for each cell  as a function of individual cells of `A` and `n` then there will be a lot of use for `pow` function. So even if this is commonly accepted answer (with which I agree as its not a good idea to go this way) its possibly not technically correct (unless I am wrong of coarse :) ). May be adding something like can not compute only by `pow` would be in place... or easily , or effectively ...